# trigger to buttons with one single button click

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to trigger to buttons by clicking on a third button. One of my buttons submits data to a PHP file and the second one loads a bootstrap modal. When I run it, I feel that both are triggered, although the submit button works fine but the bootstrap modal disappears in a blink.
this is the code:

### HTML

```
<button onclick="submitdata(); showbootstrapmodal();">Click to Trigger the two other buttons</button>

<button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" form="#myform"></button>
<button id="modal"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></button>
```

and here is the javascript code for the functions:

### javascript

```
function submitdata(){
  document.getElementById('submit').click();
  return false;
}
function showbootstrapmodal(){
  document.getElementById('modal').click();
  return false;
```

Is there a flaw in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing 'return false;' from submitdata()

```
function submitdata(){
  document.getElementById('submit').click();
}
```